# How do I set up apache virtualhosts proxies to subdomains on different docker containers

Tags: apache, docker

I have a project setup with multiple docker containers and I am trying to access a subdomain which I am trying to proxy to another container. I can achieve similar when not a sub domain, for example the following allows me to hit `localdev.com/api`:

```
<VirtualHost localdev.com:80>
    ServerName localdev.com
    SetEnv PROJECT_HOME /project/server
    SetEnv PROJECT_SERVER_ID local
    SetEnv PROJECT_ENVIRONMENT docker

    DocumentRoot /project/server/www
    <Directory /project/server/www>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Proxy *>
      Allow from localhost
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass        /api http://api.localdev.com/
    ProxyPassReverse /api http://api.localdev.com/

</VirtualHost>
```

But when I add another virtual host for `api.localdev.com`
I get forwarded to localdev (the url doesn't change in the browser but I get the content from it)

This is my subdomain virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost api.localdev.com:80>
  ServerName api.localdev.com
  <Proxy *>
    Allow from localhost
  </Proxy>
  ProxyPass        / http://api.localdev.com/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://api.localdev.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

The funny thing is in the apache logs I get the correct Host, i.e. `api.localdev.com` and from within the docker container containing `localdev.com` I can both ping & curl `api.localdev.com`

While likely not relevant to the issue, on my Mac host file I have the following to map to the docker-container

`127.0.0.1  localhost   localdev.com    api.localdev.com`

Anywhere I have looked online to try and solve this has not been clear and I will admit I find the examples confusing. Any help greatly appreciated and happy to provide any further information if I am missing anything

Comment: The containers aren't going to know about entries in your Mac /etc/hosts file - you would be better off using Docker hostname values in your proxy config.

Comment: @idg I realise that, I only have that in my mac's host so I can use localdev.com in my browser and I don't believe it is in anyway causing my issue, jut thought it may be relavant to know

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found a solution to this. Instead of creating a 2nd virtual host I added a rewrite rule for any condition with the api sub domain:

```
# proxy api subdomain to api container
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.localdev\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://api.localdev.com$1 [P]
```

Now seems to behave as expected.